# Where should I put Symfony third-party bundle's routing configuration?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-routing

I have [SonataAdminBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin), [SonataUserBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user) and [LiipImagineBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle) installed in my Symfony 2 application. According to their installation instruction, I put their routing configuration in `/app/config/routing.yml`.

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

admin:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /admin

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

When I moved them into `/src/MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`, they are also working. So, where should I put them? What is the best configuration file to put them? Why? I can't decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because we usually import our own routers in `app/config/routing.yml` file. But there are some drawbacks here, if you disable your own custom bundle they also stop working. That's why put them into `app/config/routing.yml` if you want not to break your application's functionality even if you disable your own bundles.